# Using parse.com SDK, what is the correct way to implement a "delete all user data" action?

Tags: parse-platform

We're building an application using Parse.com, and our users may want to delete their account. For this, we should also be able to guarantee to them that everything went ok, and we've deleted all data they've stored in the cloud, not just parts of it.

It seemed that the most straightforward way to do this was via Cloud Code, i.e., a logged-in user triggers a cloud function (say, "deleteUserData"), which does a few queries to build a list of everything that needs to be deleted, and then deletes them. Since the user must be logged in to do this, and the user only ever has write access to data they own, we don't risk a malevolent user deleting other user's data.

However, by the time the deletion process is done, the user object (or at least their session) has been destroyed. Everything is ok in the cloud, but the app has no way to know that its current user is now invalid. Problem is: there's no method to tell the application that it should forget this user once the deleteUserData cloud function responds with a success. There doesn't seem to exist APIs to change the "logged in" status locally in general!

If I try to logout the user in the app after this, it works... kinda. It will trigger an invalid session error and a logout error.

So, how to do it?

We can't logout the user first and then delete its data, because then the cloud function would be able to run for any user, which is insecure. We can't logout the user after the delete, because the user is already gone, and we can't fix the inconsistent state locally.

An alternative would be to write a field in the user or session object, and do something in the beforeSave / beforeDelete triggers, and then logout... but these have very strict timeout times, and we are searching for all of the user's data, which could take more time than that.

I'm a bit at a loss. Other alternatives seem to come with disadvantages too, and my current approach is to just silence the local logout errors in this particular instance, but it feels very wrong and risky. At the same time, this feels like a common operation that many applications need to be able to do. So what's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's been so long, and even Parse.com has shutdown since, I'll answer here how it should be done. This is possible with Parse Server with minor modifications to the login code:

1. Have your app respect a field in the User that marks if this user is deleted.
2. Users with this flag on can't login.
3. Data from deleted users can't be searched by the app's usual queries.
4. Have a background task that periodically searches for deleted users' data and deletes as much of them as possible before timing out. If a delete user has no more data, delete de user itself.

When you run the "deleteUserData" cloud function, you mark the user's "is deleted" field, and proceed to log them out as usual. Now they can't login, the app knows they logged out, their data will be deleted as soon as possible, but in the meantime it's also inaccessible.